# DataBindings in Winform-Custom Property Didn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

For compatible Null i covered Value property. But this property cannot use in DataBindings. it's not change when control's value update. I change the control to DateTimePicker,everything is fine.What's wrong with the Value property?

Test Class

```
class prod
{
    int id;

    public int Id {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    DateTime? md;
    public Nullable<DateTime> Md {
        get { return md; }
        set { md = value; }
    }
}
```

//Custom DateTimePicker

```
    [Bindable(true), Browsable(true)]
    public new object Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (realDate)
            {
                return base.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                return DBNull.Value; //If not a real date, sent DBNull to the bound field
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (Convert.IsDBNull(value))
            {
                realDate = false;
                oldFormat = Format; //Store the Format of the datetimepicker
                Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                CustomFormat = " "; //With this custom format, the datetimepicker is empty
            }
            else
            {
                realDate = true;
                CustomFormat = null;
                base.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
            }
            OnValueChanged();
        }
    }
```

//Binding Code:

```
    prod pp=new prod();
    datePicker1.DataBindings.Add("Value",pp,"Md",true,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);
```

i found the problem----need use WriteValue for each databinding in selectitemchanged.

Comment: Why do you say `not change when control's value update` but also say `everything is fine`?

Comment: my custom control can't update control value to the entity. change control as "DateTimePicker",the same binding code is working. but DateTimePicker can't allow a null value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged** instead of **DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation**

Comment: I've try it,not work either. It's anything wrong with the "new object Value"?